# WordPress is_home() not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress

I want `icon-backtotop.png` to appear only on the home page and `icon-backtotop-alt.png` to appear on all other pages. However, with the code below, `icon-backtotop-alt.png` shows on all pages. How can I fix this code?

```
<?php if (is_home()) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon-backtotop.png" alt="Back To Top" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon-backtotop-alt.png" alt="Back To Top" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i wanna put the title of the post in the hall of fame

Comment: Possibly a discrepancy between [is_home](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) and [is_front_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)?

Comment: Creating titles has always been an awkward situation for me.

Comment: @bizzehdee I did ask? Why so hostile? I didn't mean the post to be demanding in any way.

Comment: Now that the issue with the title is over, we can concentrate on the question in hand

Comment: @cbuckley that was it, thank you. Please post as answer.

Comment: @cbuckley Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

you probably want to use [is_front_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) not [is_home](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)

> Note: WordPress 2.1 handles this function differently than prior
>   versions - See static Front Page. If you select a static Page as your
>   frontpage (see is_front_page()), this tag will be applied to your
>   "posts page".

try

```
<?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon-backtotop.png" alt="Back To Top" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon-backtotop-alt.png" alt="Back To Top" />
<?php } ?>
```